# UWP - NavigationView with two different Sources

Tags: templates, uwp, binding, datatemplate, navigationview

I have an `ObservableCollection<Category>` binded to a `NavigationView`, where `Category` is a custom class that implements `INotifyPropertyChanged`. I created a `DataTemplate` to display the element of the collection

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="CategoryTemplate">
    <NavigationViewItem  Icon="{Binding Icon}" RightTapped="CategoryItem_RightTapped">
        <local:CategoryViewItem CategoryItem="{Binding Mode=TwoWay}"/>
    </NavigationViewItem>
</DataTemplate>
```

Now I want to add some default `NavigationViewItem` and a `NavigationViewItemSeparator` at the top of the list with a different `DataTemplate` keeping the second part "Observable" and "Notifying changes of properties". You can see an example of what I mean in the image below.

[image]

Comment: Does the following work in your side, if it's helpful please consider accept it thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For your requirement, you need make `MenuItemTemplateSelector` for `NavigationView`. And pass the different `DataTemplate` base on the data source.

**Default NavigationViewItem  and NavigationViewItemSeparator Data Model**

```
public class CategoryBase { }

public class DefaultCategory: CategoryBase
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Tooltip { get; set; }
    public Symbol Glyph { get; set; }
}
public class CustomCategory : CategoryBase
{
    public SymbolIcon Icon { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
}

public class Separator : CategoryBase { }
```

**MenuItemTemplateSelector**

```
public class MenuItemTemplateSelector : DataTemplateSelector
{
    internal DataTemplate SeparatorTemplate = (DataTemplate)XamlReader.Load(
        @"<DataTemplate xmlns='http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation'>
                <NavigationViewItemSeparator />
              </DataTemplate>");
    public DataTemplate DefaultItemTemlate { get; set; }
    public DataTemplate CustomItemTemlate { get; set; }
    protected override DataTemplate SelectTemplateCore(object item)
    {
        return item is Separator ? SeparatorTemplate : item is CustomCategory ? CustomItemTemlate : DefaultItemTemlate;
    }
}
```

**Xaml Code**

```
<Page.Resources>
    <local:MenuItemTemplateSelector x:Key="selector">
        <local:MenuItemTemplateSelector.DefaultItemTemlate>
            <DataTemplate x:DataType="local:DefaultCategory">
                <NavigationViewItem Content="{x:Bind Name}">
                    <NavigationViewItem.Icon>
                        <SymbolIcon Symbol="{x:Bind Glyph}" />
                    </NavigationViewItem.Icon>
                </NavigationViewItem>
            </DataTemplate>
        </local:MenuItemTemplateSelector.DefaultItemTemlate>
        <local:MenuItemTemplateSelector.CustomItemTemlate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <NavigationViewItem Icon="{Binding Icon}">
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Title}" />
                </NavigationViewItem>
            </DataTemplate>
        </local:MenuItemTemplateSelector.CustomItemTemlate>
    </local:MenuItemTemplateSelector>
</Page.Resources>
<Grid>
    <NavigationView
        x:Name="nvSample"
        MenuItemTemplateSelector="{StaticResource selector}"
        MenuItemsSource="{x:Bind Categories, Mode=OneWay}"
        />
    <Button Click="Button_Click" Content="AddItem" />
</Grid>
```

**Usage**

```
public MainPage()
{
    this.InitializeComponent();
    Categories = new ObservableCollection<CategoryBase>();
    Categories.Add(new CustomCategory { Title = "This is Titlte", Icon = new SymbolIcon(Symbol.Play) });
}
public ObservableCollection<CategoryBase> Categories { get; }

private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    Categories.Insert(0, new Separator());
    Categories.Insert(0, new DefaultCategory { Name = "Category 1", Glyph = Symbol.Home, Tooltip = "This is category 1" });

}
```

You could find the [code sample](https://github.com/microsoft/Xaml-Controls-Gallery) here, and this `NavigationView` [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/design/controls-and-patterns/navigationview) that  you could refer.

Comment: Thank you for sharing this solution! It looks great, but as I implemented it, the app threw an unhandled exception: `A NavigationView instance contains a Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.NavigationViewItem. This control requires that its NavigationViewItems be of type Microsoft.UI.Xaml.Controls.NavigationViewItem.` I tried to inherit the `CategoryBase` from `NavigationViewItem`, but didn't help.